# Is there an API that returns Twitter usernames?

Tags: twitter

I am looking to compile a list of URLs and associated Twitter usernames. Is there an API that you can provide a URL to and it would return a Twitter username?

Clearbit has an API for sending a URL and getting a logo in return. https://clearbit.com/

Was wondering if anyone knew of a similar API for Twitter handles.

Comment: can you clarify what kind of url your referring to? there is an api - but I am unclear if your referring to a twitter url or a company website etc

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for 
`GET users/show`

This returns a variety of information about the user specified by the required **user_id** or **screen_name** parameter.

`GET users / lookup` is used to retrieve a bulk collection of user objects.

Resource URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I don't know the user_id or screen_name. I have a URL and I want to get the screen_name.